# AWS App Runner DNS validation - Configure DNS / Configure certificate validation

Tags: aws-app-runner

### AWS App Runner DNS validation

## Configure DNS / Configure certificate validation

### Unclear instructions for validation DNS entry

1. Configure certificate validation
   Supply certificate validation records to your DNS provider within 72 hours.

```
# Record name
_d8ad1df41270f5071XXXXXXXXXXXX.uat.example.org.
```

```
# Value
_8635becd41bc57e15XXXXXXXXXXXX.htgdxnmnnj.acm-validations.aws.
```

I'm trying out the App Runner service and linking it to my domain. I'm unsure how to configure my DNS settings to prove domain ownership.

I'm unsure what kind of DNS records I need to configure - are they TXT records? CNAME?

Answer (score 1):

**AWS Support** responded saying that all of the records type should be **CNAME** records .

Yes, it is **CNAME**. If you have other domains that have SSL configured via other AWS service, you'll also see they have added CNAME records for *.acm-validations.aws.

```
DNS management for : example.org

Type: CNAME
Name: _d8ad1df41270f5071XXXXXXXXXXXX.uat.example.org.
Content: _8635becd41bc57e15XXXXXXXXXXXX.htgdxnmnnj.acm-validations.aws.
Proxy Status: DNS Only
TTL: Auto
```